# Why didn't Neo use an operator to transport him?

Tags: the-matrix

I was watching Matrix Reloaded with my sister, she asked me a question in the scene, where Neo opens the door and finds himself in Tibet and starts flying from there to city where Morpheus and Trinity are. The question is, Why did not Neo call the operator to get him out of the matrix and put him back in the area near close to the highway, by which Neo would have avoided the Superman thing and saved Morpheus and Trinity in the beginning of the fight itself?

Comment: What 'US looking'(1) city is 500 miles (AFAIR) south of Tibet?  DYM the place just gave the impression or look of Tibet?  1) OK - it was Sydney, Australia, but the *look* was supposed to be that of a typical US City.

Comment: Plus, what makes you think it's Tibet? That is never stated. He's just "in the mountains".

Comment: OK, its tibetian-like as said in http://www.themoviespoiler.com/Spoilers/matrixreloaded.html

Comment: great question. but he didn't have a hardline phone. cellphone is insufficient for this. most likely there wasn't a hardline in that part of the castle. Note that the door Neo opens here is leading to a different place than where the twin ghosts and Trinity and the Keymaker were going. The Keymaker had a key for the garage, but once the door is closed it will lead to the mountains 500 miles away intead! So he is no longer in the hotel-like building, Neo is in the castle instead - with no hardline, presumably.

Comment: The chain of events, regarding whether they are in a hotel/in the Castle may be this: They go to the Restaurant ("hotel"), they meet Persephone who leads them to the restaurant kitchen. Persephone has a key that 'transforms' the kitchen door into sg. like a teleport gate, until the time it is first closed. They are 'teleported' into the castle. In the castle the Keymaker flees and has a key to another door that transforms it into a teleport gate to Garage (*maybe* below the Restaurant). When Neo gets there the door gets closed before he gets in. Once it is closed it leads to the Castle again.

Answer (score 12):

As I recall, having an operator transfer him out of the Matrix (so he could be re-inserted nearer to Morpheus and Trinity) would have required a land-line, which wasn't present.
Probably one of the reasons Neo was lured there in the first place - no escape.

Comment: They were in a big hotel, hotels have landline.

Comment: @bobby.dreamer - I looked pretty deserted/abandoned - it was a different place to where they met Persephone (she did the door thing after walking through the Kitchen) - abandoned buildings with no landlines would make pretty good traps.

Comment: @bobby.dreamer they where in the Merovingian's villa in the Mountains, not a hotel.  There where no land lines, and even if there where, it would require 2 land lines (one exit, one entry) as well as the Operator setting up the exit, re-entry, and the physical aspects of exfil/re-insert which takes time they don't have to waste.

Comment: @Monty129 it is also notable that Neo didn't request nor waited for operator help that would show him a hardline. Even if Link wanted to provide an exit Neo wasn't interested. He maybe was confident that '500 miles should not be a big deal'. (Or alternatively he feels the missing presence of hardlines in the code:).) Or just forgot. Or...

Answer (score 8):

He's not in Tibet. Link identifies his Neo's location as being the [Merovingian's Chateau](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Chateau)

> "in the mountains"

approximately **500 miles south** of the City.

According to the Wachowski's, all of the locations seen in the Matrix films and Animatrix take place in the *same city* (described as the [Mega City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_City_%28The_Matrix%29#Locations_outside_of_Mega_City) or Metro City) and all of the hard-lines that have been "hacked" appear to be *within* the city.

Given that he'd have to fly 450 miles to find the nearest hard-line, jack out, then jack back in again to another location and then fly to Morpheus' location, it makes more sense to simply fly there in the first place.

[image: Merovingian's Chateau]