# Why did Neo fly to save Morpheus?

Tags: the-matrix

In the Matrix Reloaded movie, when Morpheus and Key maker were about to die when two trucks collided, Neo flies to the accident location and saves both of them. Why does Neo need to fly, why does he not tele-transport himself to the accident location?

Comment: Do you remember any instance, where *anybody* (including Neo) show having this ability?

Comment: In order to enter/exit the Matrix you need a hardline, there wasn't one at the Merovingian's villa in the mountains.

Comment: My answer would be "Rule of Cool".  And it you wish to waste a few delightful hours, plug "Rule of Cool tv tropes" into your favorite search engine.. I think they used the remote Villa as a device specifically to show Neo doing 'his Superman thing'.  ;)

Comment: @Monty129  Your comment got me thinking.  See my comment on the answer of bitmask.

Comment: Similar question: [Why didn't Neo use an operator to transport him?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36999/10622)

Comment: Neo could have just turned around instead of flying half way around the world

Answer (score 9):

From The Matrix, when Morpheus introduces Neo to the matrix:

> But as in many computer programs, some rules can be bent while others can be broken.

It doesn't mean Neo can do *everything*, it means, similar to a computer cracker, he can exploit weaknesses in the design of a system (i.e., the matrix). He can bend some rules in order to move really fast and he can break some in order to fly (the distinction when a rule is bent and when broken is not a clear cut, though --- especially not for the audience).

It is never even hinted, that Neo ever managed to teleport. It's just not something he could do in that system. Maybe it would be theoretically possible, we don't know, but he never figured out how.

If you are thinking about disconnecting and reconnecting, that would be really hard and risky, because it also takes a lot of time and there wasn't any hardline in the vicinity of a) his current location and b) where he had to go.
So, he had to fly to the nearest hardline (which could be quite given he was standing in the middle of nowhere), disconnect, jack back in, and then fly to the highway (which again could be far away from the nearest hardline).

Comment: Good points.  OTOH the comment of Monty129 reminded me that the players went through a door in the city and were 'instantly transported' to the villa far away.  So that indicates there *were* more fragile transport related points of the Matrix to be exploited.  Of course, that too is covered by *"Maybe it would be theoretically possible, we don't know, but **he never figured out how**."*  There is also the door the Key Maker tells them of, but that is yet to occur in the film (AFAIR).

Comment: Actually if I remember correctly, there *was* a hardline on the freeway, Trinity used it to exit the matrix, but it was destroyed  once she used it.  But the other points are very valid.

Comment: **but he never figured out how** not necessarily. Maybe Neo *can* teleport, but does not *want*. We still don't know, of course.

Comment: what if... he can teleport but only to places he knows? (possibly causing a "loud" anomaly thus endangering peers.) He doesn't actually go to the same place in the Matrix twice  very often...